# VS2008 Create Cache like functionality in Class Library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, class-library

I want to implement cache in a class library project in VS2008. Can anyone help me out with this. I tried accessing HttpRuntime.Cache but it is not possible in a class library project, are there any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried accessing HttpRuntime.Cache but it is not possible in a class
>   library project

Actually it is quite possible, just add reference to the `System.Web` assembly in your class library project.